# Sending only some data in a GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

Basically I want to only send some data back when I make a GET request to my REST API. My code for the GET request:

```
router.get('/user/all', function(req, res, next){
    User.find({name: req.query.name}).then(function(assets){
        res.send(assets);
    });
});
```

It returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "546b454b5634563b546",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@johndoe.com",
    "phoneNo": "00000000000",
    "active": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "assets": [
      {
        "name": "house",
        "location": {
          "_id": "592190ce29f12e179446d837",
          "coordinates": [
            -81.5,
            24.1
          ],
          "type": "point"
        },
        "_id": "592190ce29f12e179446d836"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want it to return only:

```
[
   {
     "name": "house",
     "location": {
     "_id": "592190ce29f12e179446d837",
     "coordinates": [
       -81.5,
        24.1
      ],
      "type": "point"
    },
    "_id": "592190ce29f12e179446d836"
  }
]
```

How can I change the API request to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to return only the assets, then try this:

```
router.get('/user/all', function(req, res, next){
    User.find({name: req.query.name}).then(function(assets){
        res.send(assets.map(function(x) {return x.assets;}))
    });
});
```